# How to convert the WebElement to RepoItemInfo object in Ranorex

Tags: c#, ranorex

In Ranorex I can to converted RepoItemInfo into WebElement, using `FindAdapter<T>()` on WebElement object, but I do not know how to do it backwards?

```
RepoItemInfo info = someWebElement.???();
```

Comment: Is the Web element available in your repo or are you building it during the run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element needs to be in your Ranorex repository. Once added, you can access the element's info object from the repository object.
[image]

Comment: Yes, it true. But how to create RepoItemInfo object in runtime? FE: `SomeMethod(WebElement we){ RepoItemInfo ri = we.???;]

Comment: You should not be doing this and should be using the Ranorex Repository to define the repo items. Not using the repository is going to create a LOT of extra work and maintenance for your test.